# In OpenLayers 3, how do I write on the map?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have made an OpenLayers 3 web application I use while driving. It would be very handy to have the speed of the car in one corner of the map. Is it possible to achieve this so that the text (numbers) are locked to the viewport of the map rather than the map itself. I'm thinking of something similar to the controls of the map.

I suppose I could put it below the map but then I'm afraid I would run into problems with different sizes of screens.

Could somebody suggest a technique I should look into?

Comment: Correct, a text control would be the correct way. You can see on JSFiddle that it works even on a small area: http://jsfiddle.net/o18y4km4/

Comment: Thank you very much for Your help.